# Запрос в mysql

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть слово "Кофта", в бд есть 2 записи в поле name varchar 255 Зеленая кофта с пуговками, оранжевая кофта.

Как правильно сделать запрос в бд, чтобы совершить поиск в бд по столбцу name значений, которые содержат слово "Кофта", и при этом не учитывать регистр?

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select `column1`,`column2` from `table` where LOWER(`name`) like LOWER('%Кофта%')
```

Comment: Соррь за первый вариант, он из постгреса.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.